# How do I get my code to echo only once instead of twice?

Tags: php, mysql

My code echo's `Hey` or `Hello` twice once the requirements are met.

This is supposed to check whether or not a person has something uploaded, depending on if they do or don't either message displays.

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $sqlImg = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE idUsers='$current'";
        $resultImg = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlImg);
        while ($rowImg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultImg)) {
            if ($rowImg['profile_img'] == 0) {
                echo "hey";
            } else {
                echo "Hello";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output to echo either word once, but the actual output is echoing it twice.

Comment: weird code. why the 2 selects?

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($resultImg->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC))`

Comment: It will output the word as many times as there are rows in the table, because of the outer loop.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need two loops. The outer loop is running for every user in the table, regardless of whether they match `$current`. For each of them you're doing another query that just gets the `$current` user, and echoing their status.

If `idUsers` is a unique key, you don't even need any loops. Just do one query and fetch the row.

You should also use a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT profile_img FROM users WHERE idUsers = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $current);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$rowImg = $result->fetch_assoc();
if ($rowImg['profile_img'] == 0) {
    echo "hey";
} else {
    echo "Hello";
}
```